# Radio buttons inside the slides of a carousel aren't working

Tags: javascript, materialize

I am using owl-carousel-2 to set up a slide show which has a quiz in it.

Quiz is being populated using a JSON object.

q is a question from the Quiz.
For each of the options of this question, I am making a "input" element with a label.

The code runs without any error. The radio button on the first slide also work as expected. However, slide 2 on wards, the radio buttons have got inaccessible or are not responding

```
q.options.forEach(function(opt, i) {
  let optionX = document.createElement("div");
  optionX.className = "-option";
  optionX.addEventListener("click", function() {
                console.log("click -option div logged" + index + "|" + i)
            });

  let ip = document.createElement("input");
  ip.setAttribute("type", "radio");
  ip.setAttribute("id", "rd-" + index + "X" + i);
  ip.setAttribute("name", "Q" + index);
  ip.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("radio click logged")
  });

  let lbl = document.createElement("label");
  lbl.setAttribute("for", "rd-" + index + "X" + i);
  lbl.innerText = opt.text;

  optionX.appendChild(ip);
  optionX.appendChild(lbl);

  optCntr.appendChild(optionX);
}
```

When i click on a label on the first slide, those console.logs shows 3 click - first on the "-option" div, then the radio button and then again on the "-option" div. But when I click on a label on the second slide only one click is being registered - on the "-option" div.

Please help!